# How to read flight manifest from txt file and store on the datagrid view

Tags: c#

I am going to develop an airline embarkation program in c#, and i don't know how to read flight manifest from txt file and convert to excel/store on the datagridview?

the flight manifest is on the txt is like:

ENHANCED PASSENGER MANIFEST
FLIGHT: ET  200             DATE: 01SEP16

### A/C REG. ETANV          PT.OF EMBARKATION: ADD          PT.OF DEST: GDE

LNAME/FNAME/TYPE/SEAT/BAGS/WEIGHT/BAGTAG/TKT#/IN.FLT/TR.ORG/OT.FLT/F.DST/SPECIAL

Y CLASS

001 ABDELA/SEID../M./24L/..1/..30/437913/0711726941217/......./.../......./.../....
002 ABDI/MAHAMOUD/M./19L/..2/..20/437862/0712115502724/......./.../......./.../....
.                                 437863
TOTALS:   MALE  FEMALE  CHILD   INFANT  BAGS    WEIGHT

.          38     10      4       2      31       347

### TOTALS PASSANGERS:

TOTALS:   MALE  FEMALE  CHILD   INFANT  BAGS    WEIGHT
.          38     10      4       2      31       347

IN.FLT/TR.ORGN/OT.FLT/F.SDT
INBOUND FLIGHT/TRUE ORIGIN/OUTBOUND FLIGHT/FINAL DESTINATION

Comment: Which part of the `text` file you want to fetch?

Comment: How would you like the columns in DGV to look?

Comment: i want to read all the text file, and display it on datagridview tabular style

Comment: Read line by line, split the data by the seperator. Put all data in a class. Bind the class to the DGV.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below.  I only got up to passenger list, but you can finish code.  Once all data is parsed you can then add info to your form :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";

        enum State
        {
            GET_FLIGHT,
            EMBARKATION,
            PASSENGER_HEADER,
            CLASS,
            PASSENGERS,
            DONE
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);

            State state = State.GET_FLIGHT;

            string flight = "";
            DateTime date;
            string embarkation = "";
            string destination = "";
            string _class = "";


            string inputline = "";
            while((inputline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (inputline.Trim().Length  > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case State.GET_FLIGHT :
                            string flightPattern = @"FLIGHT:\s+(?'flight'.+)DATE:\s+(?'date'[^$]+)$";
                            Match flightDate = Regex.Match(inputline, flightPattern);
                            flight = flightDate.Groups["flight"].Value.Trim();
                            string dateStr = flightDate.Groups["date"].Value.Trim();
                            date = DateTime.Parse(dateStr);

                            state = State.EMBARKATION;
                            break;

                        case State.EMBARKATION :
                            string embarkPattern = @"EMBARKATION:\s+(?'embarkation'.+)DEST:\s+(?'dest'[^$]+)$";
                            Match embarkDest = Regex.Match(inputline, embarkPattern);
                            embarkation = embarkDest.Groups["embarkation"].Value.Trim();
                            destination = embarkDest.Groups["dest"].Value.Trim();

                            state = State.PASSENGER_HEADER;
                            break;

                        case State.PASSENGER_HEADER:
                            state = State.CLASS;
                            break;

                        case State.CLASS :
                            _class = inputline;

                            state = State.PASSENGERS;
                            break;

                        case State.PASSENGERS :
                            Passenger.GetPassengers(inputline);
                            state = State.DONE;
                            break;

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        public class Passenger
        {
            public static List<Passenger> passengers = new List<Passenger>();

            public string number { get; set; }
            public string lName {get; set;}
            public string fName {get; set;}
            public string type { get; set;}
            public string seat { get; set; }
            public string bags {get; set; }
            public string weight { get; set; }
            public string tag { get; set;}
            public string ticket { get; set;}
            public string inFlight {get; set; }
            public string trOrg { get; set;}
            public string otFlt { get; set;}
            public string fDst { get; set; }
            public string special { get; set; }
            //LNAME/FNAME/TYPE/SEAT/BAGS/WEIGHT/BAGTAG/TKT#/IN.FLT/TR.ORG/OT.FLT/F.DST/SPECIAL

            public static void GetPassengers(string inputline)
            {
                string endPattern = @"(?'passengers'.+)\.\s\d+\sTOTALS:";
                Match passengersMatch = Regex.Match(inputline, endPattern);
                string passengers = passengersMatch.Groups["passengers"].Value.Trim();

                string passengerPattern = 
                          @"(?'no'\d+)\s" +
                          @"(?'lname'[^/]+)/" +
                          @"(?'fname'[^/]+)/" +
                          @"(?'type'[^/]+)/" +
                          @"(?'seat'[^/]+)/" +
                          @"(?'bags'[^/]+)/" +
                          @"(?'weight'[^/]+)/" +
                          @"(?'tag'[^/]+)/" +
                          @"(?'ticket'[^/]+)/" +
                          @"(?'inFlight'[^/]+)/" +
                          @"(?'trOrg'[^/]+)/" +
                          @"(?'otFlt'[^/]+)/" +
                          @"(?'fDst'[^/]+)/" +
                          @"(?'special'[\w\.]+)";

                MatchCollection  passengerMatch = Regex.Matches(passengers, passengerPattern);
                foreach (Match match in passengerMatch)
                {
                    Passenger newPassenger = new Passenger();
                    Passenger.passengers.Add(newPassenger);

                    newPassenger.number = match.Groups["no"].Value;
                    newPassenger.lName = match.Groups["lname"].Value;
                    newPassenger.fName = match.Groups["fname"].Value;
                    newPassenger.type = match.Groups["type"].Value;
                    newPassenger.seat = match.Groups["seat"].Value;
                    newPassenger.bags = match.Groups["bags"].Value;
                    newPassenger.weight = match.Groups["weight"].Value;
                    newPassenger.tag = match.Groups["tag"].Value;
                    newPassenger.ticket = match.Groups["ticket"].Value;
                    newPassenger.inFlight = match.Groups["inFlight"].Value;
                    newPassenger.trOrg = match.Groups["trOrg"].Value;
                    newPassenger.otFlt = match.Groups["otFlt"].Value;
                    newPassenger.fDst = match.Groups["fDst"].Value;
                    newPassenger.special = match.Groups["special"].Value; 

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```